# Deep Freeze Removing Group Policy?

Tags: groups

I am having trouble applying group policies on computers with deep freeze installed on them. They are domain joined and pulling updates from our WSUS server before being frozen. When we freeze them they seem to lose their group policy settings. I have tried thawing, gpupdate/ force, and then refreezing, but they lose their group policy as soon as they are brought back up. What could be causing this? Everything was working fine until a bad Windows update came through. We blocked the update on our WSUS server and thawed, removed the update, and re-froze all the computers. The next day I came to work to find out that all the computers had reached out to the Internet and pulled the bad update again.

Comment: On boot and logon stuff happens, like refreshing GPOs, which in turn writes to your C:\windows\system32\GroupPolicy.  When taking the snapshot with Deep Freeze, are you sure that there are files located in that directory?  Otherwise, they will be "removed" by Deep Freeze upon reboot, obviously.  You can enable symmetric logons, but this will slow down the logon process ([HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon REG_DWORD:SyncForegroundPolicy](http://goo.gl/44aXA)).  Sounds ironic since it's a GPO, but maybe control this reg value in your image?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer about Deep Freeze but this is the kind of problems that this type of software generates.
The software freeze the machine in a point of the time, and everything you do is lost when the machine is restart. That is  bad thing because machines stops to taking changes of important things like updates.
These type of software let you make execptions to dont have this issues, but in lots of cases still fails.

Some time ago Microsoft had a software like this called Steady State for Windows Xp but for Windows 7 it was disccontinuated.

¿Why?
Because this kind of software is not necessary. With Windows natively you can have mandatory profiles, a type of user profile that lost all the changes when the user close his session.

So my recommendation here is dont use Deep Freeze, Windows natively can do to a similar behavior with lots of advantages for free.
Microsoft has a guide to do this using GPos and mandatory profiles: [Creating a Steady State by Using Microsoft Technologies](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/springboard/archive/2010/09/27/steady-state-for-windows-7.aspx)

Comment: Deep Freeze offers benefits that you don't find with mandatory profiles. For example, when you have someone mucking with the Windows directory, deep freeze means nothing is altered after reboot. Users with mandatory profiles can in some cases still alter outside directories and files, and malware can take advantage of exploits in the system. With DF, the damage is limited to just the user profile and home directories.

Comment: @BartSilverstrim this is true only for admin users, but in a traditional enviroment like describe in the guide above a User NEVER can change a Windows Directory or a local machine registry hive.

About the virus you are right, but if you freeze your machine lots of times your antivirus wont be update and you will have lots of issues when the machine starts.

Comment: Additionally, there are cases where for some reason the profile/gpo doesn't "take". If a system isn't communicating with the network properly, DF still protects the machine from tampering.

Comment: If the machine isn't communicating with the network properly GPOs are not affected becase they are cached until the next contact with the DC.

Comment: Not if the new GPO is what you need on the machine.

Comment: As for the user NEVER changing the Windows directory, you haven't used the software we used. It was storing data in the Windows directory. Depends on your environment.

Comment: As for AV, the machines we freeze don't typically have AV on them because the database can't update across restarts (other than Windows built-in Defender on them). They're rendered moot anyway; we use AV at points where data is altered (like home and share servers). If a frozen machine has an issue, you restart it. That's kind of the point. Although I believe Faronics is working on (or has) an AV solution meant to work with their product.

Comment: I don't know what the issues you refer to are at machine start, unless you mean it can flood a server with requests for updates if you have a start en-masse and the machines all try updating AV at once. I don't know why you'd opt for that config though.

Comment: Bart the point here is: is ok to do no have av because you restart the computer and the virus dissaperar. But this is a bad thing, because while the PC is On the user is not secure. If you dont have the computer updated or AV you the user will be working in an insecure enviroment with vulnerabilites and its privacy is higly on risk.

Comment: I'm not going to draw this into a long discussion, since this is a non-canonical topic, but AV and such are fallible; you can't guarantee that you'll be protected against all malware, and you also have to deal with false positives on occasion. Users are far more likely to give up their privacy on their own with perfectly "allowed" methods, and through social engineering. FAR more likely.

Comment: Last, you probably don't know what environment I work in, but this model works for our situation. Everything in security has tradeoffs. Quite frankly it's a little silly to run AV on a frozen system. And your model of just locking the profile or making mandatory profiles *doesn't work for us.* Unfortunately IT doesn't dictate policy; our users have certain requirements, we have to get it to work. And some of those programs screw around with directories that they *shouldn't*, but do. And malware can still break out into other areas on the PC.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is the group policy setting (or settings) being lost? Deep Freeze will keep the settings on the machine as they were (unless they're updated during, say, a maintenance window), but it can still be overridden at runtime. Just like with viruses. Deep Freeze will protect the machine from infection in that when you reboot, it's gone; but it can still be infected during runtime.

Also if there are alterations during runtime the policy may get overridden. I.e., user-specific settings from their portions of the registry (pulled from a profile) will take effect at login, just like if they have malware in their profile it'll infect the machine each time they log in and get wiped when restarted (assuming the profile isn't part of the freeze state.)

The bad update shouldn't matter if the machine is frozen. Restarting will eliminate it, unless they're doing it over a maintenance thaw. One solution to that is to either alter your DNS records so you can't reach the Windows Update server except from your WSUS server (not a great solution) or blocking access at a proxy or firewall except for your server.

Comment: The machines are scheduled to thaw every night at 1 am, pull updates from wsus, then freeze again at 4 am. The bad update is blocked on our wsus server, but the machines keep pulling the bad update from windows when they thaw instead of hitting wsus. The policy that turns off automatic updates is not being applied... I can force it but as soon as I refreeze, the machine loses the policy. All of our staff and faculty computers that do not have deep freeze are taking the gpo like they are supposed to, so I'm assuming it's a conflict with deepfreeze.

Comment: Interesting. I'd almost think there's corruption with a registry hive doing it, if you only had this happen to select machines that had the update on them first.

Comment: DF itself *shouldn't* be affecting policy. We've had corrupted hives do weird things, though. And it's odd that it's tied to that update going on the system first.

Answer (score 0):

Deep Freeze administrator (DFAdmin.exe) has the ability to configure Windows updates and will override GPO settings. In order to fix this either:

1. Deploy a RDX file that tells deepfreeze not to configure windows updates (GPO will apply).
2. Deploy a RDX file that tells deepfreeze to use the WSUS server.

Both of these are done through the "Windows Update" on the Deep Freeze Administrator console.